# How to send this request to websockets using the `ws` library

Tags: javascript, node.js, ws

I am working with a private API, trying to send the following request with websockets using the `ws` library. I can get this request to work using the [Simple WebSocket Client extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-websocket-client/pfdhoblngboilpfeibdedpjgfnlcodoo/related?hl=en) in Google Chrome, but everything I've tried with `ws` is not working. The websockets connection is established. I know this because I'm getting a generic heartbeat message and I'm able to get events for other purposes. But this simple piece has me stumped, mostly because the private API's documentation for websockets usage sparse, to say the least, if not completely non-existent.

Request: `{"message":"ping"}`

My code:

```
            const ws = new WebSocket(channelData.connectUri)
            ws.onerror = error => {
                console.log('Connection Error', error)
            }
            ws.onopen = () => {
                console.log("Connected")
                ws.emit("message", {"message":"ping"}) // this sends me my own message
                // it should send me this:
                // {"topicName": "channel.metadata", "eventBody": {"message": "pong"}}

                // ws.emit("message", "ping") // attempted this also, without success
            }
            ws.on("message", msg => console.log(msg))
```

I have tried using `ws.send({"message":"ping"})` but I get this error:

```
node:buffer:323
  throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(
  ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received an instance of Object
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:329:5)
    at Function.from (node:buffer:323:9)
    at toBuffer (/Users/user/Documents/GitHub/lib/node_modules/ws/lib/buffer-util.js:97:18)
    at Sender.send (/Users/user/Documents/GitHub/lib/node_modules/ws/lib/sender.js:261:17)
    at WebSocket.send (/Users/user/Documents/GitHub/lib/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:361:18)
    at WebSocket.ws.onopen (/Users/user/Documents/GitHub/lib/server.js:55:20)
    at WebSocket.onOpen (/Users/user/Documents/GitHub/lib/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:144:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:378:20)
    at WebSocket.setSocket (/Users/user/Documents/GitHub/lib/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:177:10)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Documents/GitHub/lib/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:671:15) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

This `ws.send("message", "ping")` does nothing.

Comment: did you consider using `send`, like on any normal websocket? `ws` is spec-compliant and the client behaves like the normal browser websocket?

Comment: Yes, but I get an error. I've added it to my question...

Comment: Maybe you should read a minimal working websocket example, and see [how websocket works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/send#parameters). PS: the error message even states that very explicitly.

Comment: I know how websockets works. Nothing I've attempted has worked for this, which is why I'm asking the question, because clearly I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only send `String` or `Buffer` data with `WebSocket.prototype.send`. Fortunately, `JSON.parse` + `JSON.stringify` quickly bridge the gap between structured data (`Object`, `Array`, etc.) and `String`.

Try:

```
ws.send(JSON.stringify({"message":"ping"}));
```

The receiving end will get a `String`, not an `Object` - in order to recreate the structured data, you can then perform:

```
let structuredData = JSON.parse(stringReceivedFromWebSocket);
```

Comment: Thanks - appreciate the confirmation and nice answer.